# Is it possible to upload apps to google play with team account?

Tags: android, google-play

I am not talking about an app for a team, but something like iTunes where a user (say the boss) has a main account and it can choose team member with abilities for publish new apps or updates.

I can not find this option in google play. is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add multiple Google Accounts. One is the owner and he can give other access. But you have to do this in the Google Developer Console.

Log in into your account. Press Settings. Click the button Invite new user.

Sorry, I use Dutch language, but here is a screenshot:
[image]